# How to stop foreach loop on c#

Tags: c#, xml

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(@"XMLFile1.xml");
Kullanıcılar _kullanici = new Kullanıcılar();
string password = pnb2.Password; 
foreach (XElement element2 in doc.Descendants("sif"))
{
    foreach (XElement element1 in doc.Descendants("iban"))
    {
        foreach (XElement element3 in doc.Descendants("accountno"))
        {
            foreach (XElement element4 in doc.Descendants("money"))
            {               
                foreach (XElement element8 in doc.Descendants("acc"))
                {
                    string val1 = element2.Value;
                    string val2 = element1.Value;
                    string val3 = element3.Value;
                    string val4 = element4.Value;
                    string val8 = element8.Value;
                    if (val8 == "1" && val1 == "Abdullah")
                    {                                               
                        lbl1.Content = ("İban Numaranız :" + val2);
                        lbl2.Content = ("Hesap Numaranız :" + val3);
                        lbl3.Content = ("Bakiyeniz :" + val4);
                    }
                }  
            }
        }
    }
}
```

How can I stop this loop ? If `val8="1"` and `val1=="Abdullah"` I would like
to show my data on the screen but this loop is entering an endless loop
so nothing shows on the screen.

Comment: if (val8="1" and val1=="Abdullah" )
{return;}

Comment: @viveknuna `break` would be better here

Comment: @wudzik: Almost certainly not - if the OP wants to quit the whole 5-level-nested set of loops at that point, then putting it in a separate method and returning is probably the best approach.

Comment: However, the code we've got here will *not* go into an endless loop... my guess is that there's something else wrong.

Comment: use `goto` be man! =)

Comment: @teovankot Careful, some people might think you are serious ;)

Comment: Side note: you might want to consider using an XPath query instead of looping like this.

Comment: Or a LINQ query. Note that it's unlikely that you *really* want to use `doc.Descendants` in every case - I'd expect `foreach (XElement element1 in element2.Descendants("iban"))` for example. Otherwise you've got 5 entirely independent sequences you're iterating over.

Comment: thx for all comment :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixed error in this way:

```
if (val8 == "1" && val1 == "Abdullah")
{
    lbl1.Content = ("Iban Numaraniz :" + val2);
    lbl2.Content = ("Hesap Numaraniz :" + val3);
    lbl3.Content = ("Bakiyeniz :" + val4);
    return;
}
```

Comment: Just change the val1 chekc in your first loop, this will give you performance boost: `if(element2.Value != "Abdullah")
         continue;`

Answer (score 2):

or you could try using "break" to stop the loop.

```
if (val8 == "1" && val1 == "Abdullah")
{                                               
     lbl1.Content = ("İban Numaranız :" + val2);
     lbl2.Content = ("Hesap Numaranız :" + val3);
     lbl3.Content = ("Bakiyeniz :" + val4);
     break; //stops the loop
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could make use of a `goto` statement:

```
if (val8 == "1" && val1 == "Abdullah")
{
    lbl1.Content = ("İban Numaranız :" + val2);
    lbl2.Content = ("Hesap Numaranız :" + val3);
    lbl3.Content = ("Bakiyeniz :" + val4);
    goto Finished;
}
```

The label `Finished` should be placed after the closing bracket of the outer most `foreach` (`XElement element2 in doc.Descendants("sif")`). Something like the following does your job:

```
Finished: 
    ;
```

You could check this at [dot-net-fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/THUxcO).

Comment: That will only break from the innermost loop, which probably isn't what's intended.

Comment: @Christos that's the best answer :)